# ExoPlayer error: ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001019, internalError -2147483648)

Tags: android, react-native, exoplayer, react-native-video

I encountered an error when using [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video) to play `m3u8`. What caused this?

`m3u8` comes with a `key`, some can be played, some cannot be played

```
08-13 14:12:45.847 E/ACodec: [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -1010
08-13 14:12:45.878 E/ACodec: [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] ERROR(0x80001019)
08-13 14:12:45.878 E/ACodec: signalError(omxError 0x80001019, internalError -2147483648)
08-13 14:12:45.884 E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0x80001019, actionCode 0, while in state 6
08-13 14:12:45.922 E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Internal runtime error.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_dequeueOutputBuffer(Native Method)
```

Comment: Similar problem, but no solution： https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5230